# VBA Macro Not Working On XLS Compatibility Mode`

Tags: excel, vba, xlsx, xls, backwards-compatibility

This macro works w/ .xlsx files to open a two reference files to pull up different descriptive data using "Style" as the primary key. It searches from left to right of the active cell and references the first valid "style" (using the "Stylemaster.xlsx" file as a lexicon) for the Vlookup equation that is injected into the active cell at the end.

Is there a command in this that cant be used for .XLS files? Or am I missing something here.

The two files will open and hide after executing and the do while will execute, but the active cell will be left blank.

```
Sub StyleINVLookLeft()
Dim form
Dim x As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim col As Integer
Dim leng As Integer
Dim cel
Dim flg


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

On Error Resume Next
    Set wb = Workbooks("INV Master.xlsx")
    If Err Then
    wb = Workbooks.Open("J:\INV Master.xlsx")
    End If

On Error Resume Next
    Set x = Workbooks("BC Style Master ALL2.xlsx")
    If Err Then
    x = Workbooks.Open("J:\BC Style Master ALL2.xlsx")
    End If

If Right(ActiveWorkbook.Path, 3) = "xls" Then
flg = 1
col = -1
GoTo Skipsearch
End If


flg = 0
col = -13

TryAgain:

col = col + 1

With ActiveCell
    On Error Resume Next
    cel = ActiveCell.Offset(0, col)
    leng = Len(cel)
        Do While leng <> 6 And col > -13 And col < 12
        col = col + 1
            On Error Resume Next
        cel = ActiveCell.Offset(0, col)
        leng = Len(cel)
            If col > 300 Then MsgBox "Error: Infinite Loop Triggered"
            If col > 300 Then End
        Loop

If col >= 12 And leng <> 6 Then
    col = -1
    flg = 1
End If

End With

Skipsearch:

If IsError(Application.VLookup(cel, x.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a:A"), 1, 0)) And flg = 0 Then
    GoTo TryAgain
End If

ActiveCell.formula = "=VLOOKUP(RC[" & col & "],'[INV Master.xlsx]Style INV'!c1:c8,7,FALSE)"
            form = Left(ActiveCell.formula, 9) & "$" & Right(ActiveCell.formula, Len(ActiveCell.formula) - 9)
            ActiveCell.Select
            ActiveCell.formula = form
            form = ""

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True

Workbooks("INV Master.xlsx").Windows(1).Visible = False
Workbooks("BC Style Master ALL2.xlsx").Windows(1).Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Do not rely on `ActiveCell`, how can you guarantee that it is where you expect it to be? You cannot. It also doesn't help that you are ignoring or disabling most errors. You need to discover errors to realise what might be going wrong.

Comment: The objective of  this macro to be used to quickly reference a style for descriptive data, so it wont be used for a standardized report or sheet. 

Do you have a better alternative that I should use?

As for ignoring errors, I understand the concern on catching potential errors, but I do have handlers for most of them that seem to be working as intended.

Comment: I take it those two `Workbook.Open` lines weren't meant to be split across two lines (I've edited to one line)?

Comment: `"INV Master.xlsx"` isn't used after you open it.... tell a lie, it's used in the `VLOOKUP` formula at the end with text referencing it, but the variable is never used.

Comment: `If Right(ActiveWorkbook.Path, 3) = "xls" Then` won't work as the line before it you open an `xlsx` so the `Activebook` at that point will always be 2007+

Comment: That is correct Darren on the Workbook.Open bit. Thank you.

"INV Master.xlsx" is used at the end for the vlookup injected into the active cell and his hidden in the background for future use

Comment: Unfortunately, even w/out "If Right(ActiveWorkbook.Path, 3) = "xls" Then", the equation does not inject into the active cell. 

This bit of the macro was inserted when I assumed the do while loop was my problem

Comment: The `ActiveCell` will be whatever cell was active last time the workbook was closed on whichever sheet was active.  The main question we should've asked first off though was _how is it not working_?  Does it do nothing, does it crash, does it stop on a specific line and give an error message?  At the moment you turn error checking off at the start and never turn it back on again so I expect it appears to do nothing?

Comment: Rather than checking for the ".xls" you could check if `activeworkbook.FileFormat = 56` [FileFormat Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat)

Comment: The macro opens the workbooks at first as intended, runs the do while loop but does not insert the excel equation at the end into the active cell.

Comment: It'll probably be throwing an error somewhere - `On Error Resume Next` will be hiding that.

Comment: The error seems to be in 'ActiveCell.formula = "=VLOOKUP(RC[" & col & "],'[INV Master.xlsx]Style INV'!c1:c8,7,FALSE)"
            form = Left(ActiveCell.formula, 9) & "$" & Right(ActiveCell.formula, Len(ActiveCell.formula) - 9)
            ActiveCell.Select
            ActiveCell.formula = form
            form = ""'

Comment: I was able to fix it by fixing the reference in 'ActiveCell = "=VLOOKUP(RC[" & col & "],'[INV Master.xlsx]Pattern INV'!r1c1:r60000c8,7,FALSE)" ' because formulas in XLS  files cannot reference columns longer than ~60000 rows. 

Thank you for the help, though.